# DROP Multiple Tables in Database using Databricks

Tags: scala, databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to drop multiple tables in databrick scala using the following command

```
select 'DROP TABLE ' + tableName from ABC where tableName LIKE 'in%'
```

Error results saying

Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Table or view not found: ABC

However the ABC database is present

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't work this way... You need to use [SHOW TABLES IN ... LIKE ...](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-tables.html) in combination with the explicit deletes.  Something like this (in Python):

```py
db_name = "ABC"
pattern = "in*"
tables = spark.sql(f"SHOW TABLES IN {db_name} LIKE '{pattern}'")
for row in tables.collect():
  spark.sql(f"DROP TABLE {db_name}.{row[1]}")
```

Comment: @hsop at time of answer, the `%` characters was used...

Answer (score 1):

I found the following way in scala

```
val dbName="ABC"
val df = spark.sql(s"""show tables from """+ dbName)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_tables")
val temp_tables = spark.sql("""select tableName from temp_tables where tableName like 'in%' """)

temp_tables.collect().foreach(row => println("DROP TABLE " + dbName + "."+ row.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "")))
```